# Advanced-N 6205 with x230 not visible

Tags: 13.04, wireless, networking, lenovo, intel-wireless

I recently upgraded my Lenovo x230 with an advanced-N 6205 wireless card from ebay (I just swapped them over).

As I understand it, this should just work out of the box on 13.04, but unfortunately I get nothing at all on the user end. I've read that the x230 requires a lenovo specific wireless card, so I was initially worried that it was something to do with this, but I got it working just fine under Windows 7 (after installing the drivers through the lenovo tool).

The card is visible with `lspci` and `iwlwifi` is loaded.

`sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` yields:

```
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

`lspci -vv` yields the following:

```
DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+ FLReset-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <4us, L1 <32us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Device Serial Number 00-15-00-ff-ff-62-df-09
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

I'm completely mystified on this one. I just expected it to work and can't see why it isn't!

Might the firmware be non-standard? If that, I would have expected others to have a similar problem. Is there something about the way I installed it that is problematic?

Answer (score 1):

Well that was rather stupid. I'd installed the backports wireless driver stack for the crappy card I had in previously. This completely broke the Intel driver installed previously.

Rebuilding the backports drivers including the `iwldriver` fixed everything.

Worked out the problem with `dmesg | grep iwl` and google.